# Getting array boundary exception that is so weird

Tags: c++, 2d

I'm trying to implement a space invader game, now I'm trying to check if bullets hit an invader, then I remove it.

I'm ONLY get an exception when I try to shoot the last invader in the row. 
For e.g If I have just one row and 8 invaders, the last one, when the bullet hits it, I got a strange boundary out of exception.

The initialization is like that, in pseudo code:

```
struct Invaders_t
{
    vector<Invader*> *invaders;
}
for (int j = 0; j < 1; j++)
    {
        x_spacing = 15;
        for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
        {
            Invader *invader = new Invader();
            g_Invaders.invaders->push_back(invader);

    }
```

for each frame:

```
for (int x = 0; x < 1; x++)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < 8; y++)
            {
                Invader *pInvader = (*(g_Invaders.invaders))[x*8 + y];

                if (pInvader != nullptr && pInvader->AlienAtals->GetImage() != nullptr)
                {

                    for (list<Bullet*>::iterator it = ship->Bullets->begin(); it != ship->Bullets->end(); it++)
                    {
                        float left = (*it)->Position.x - 5;
                        float top = (*it)->Position.y - 13;

                        if (CheckCollision(left, top, pInvader->AlienSprite->m_X, pInvader->AlienSprite->GetImage()->GetWidth()/4
                            , pInvader->AlienSprite->m_Y, pInvader->AlienSprite->GetImage()->GetHeight()/4))
                        {
                            std::vector<Invader*>::iterator iter = g_Invaders.invaders->begin();
                            std::advance(iter, (x *8) + y);
                            Invader *invader = *iter;
                            g_Invaders.invaders->erase(iter);
                            delete invader;
                        }

                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Please provide a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @Barry, the example is above, iterating over invaders, then check for each bullet if it hits it.

Comment: That example is neither minimal, nor complete, nor verifiable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you delete an invader (`g_Invaders.invaders->erase(iter);`), the size of the vector decreases by 1 (all vector's elements after `iter` shift by 1 position to the beginning, filling the vacant space). Your code doesn't expect this and continues iterating over the vector as if still had the full set of elements.

Comment: but why only that last element in the vector ? why it crashes at that specific element?  What's the solution to my current problem :S ?

Comment: I suspect it crashes on accessing the last (8th) element in the vector because it's not there, when a bullet hits some invader before the 8th element (or maybe the bullet hits several of them at once, it's difficult to tell). One of possible solutions would be to reverse your loops, so that the invaders are always iterated from last to first.

Comment: doing that, caused a crash from the first time:
for (int x = 1; x > 0; x--)
  {
   for (int y = 8; y > 0; y--)
   {
    Invader *pInvader = (*(g_Invaders.invaders))[x*8 + y];

Comment: I'm afraid you reversed the loops incorrectly. In your original code, x iterates through 0...0, and y iterates through 0...7. In your reversed loops, you have x=1 (not 0) and y iterating through 8 to 1 (not from 7 to 0).

Comment: @andreahmed You're running this under a debugger, *right* ? If not, learn how to, find out more about your crashes that *only you can reproduce* as you've chosen not to post reproducible code, and bring said-crash info and backtraces here. Advice: *Don't use unchecked `operator[]` from a vector until you know your code is functioning properly*. Use the vector's `.at()` member function which includes bounds checking and will tell you *immediately* when you're out of range while debugging. Also, avoid naked pointers at all costs in modern C++ programs. There are better ways.

Comment: @Inspired still I get an exception when I try to destroy the last invader in just one row for (int x = 1; x > 0; x--)
  {
   for (int y = 7; y > 0; y--)
   {
    Invader *pInvader = (*(g_Invaders.invaders))[x*0 + y];
}
} 
that's so weird

Comment: @Inspired is there any other solutions ? I'm interested

Comment: @Inspired do you have any idea :S ?

Comment: x is still 1, not zero.

Comment: @Inspired can you write a peudo-code please.  still didn't got it right

Comment: for (int x = 0; x >=0; x--)